# Curl request fails

Tags: php, xml, curl, xml-parsing

I have a small issue. I want to load this page 'http://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=57084011597&format=rss20' using curl. Here is the code I am trying t use, nut I can't get aything back from it.

```
    $head=array('Accept'=>'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
                    'Accept-Charset'=>'ISO-8859-2,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
                    'Accept-Encoding'=>'gzip,deflate,sdch',
                    'Accept-Language'=>'ro-RO,ro;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4',
                    'Cache-Control'=>'max-age=0',
                    'Connection'=>'keep-alive',
                    'Cookie'=>'datr=hroHTi2NZk2KleOaswb03Q_Q; lu=gg9lJcPeInHt6hnut7bviqQg; locale=en_US; e=n; L=2; c_user=100000596376783; sct=1309129360; xs=2%3Ad05dd80e364608525dd664ad73f6483f; act=1309410851554%2F5; presence=EM309410852L4N0_5dEp_5f1B00596376783F1X309410852168Y0Z11G309410768PCC',
                    'Host'=>'www.facebook.com',
                    'User-Agent'=>$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);  
$url='http://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=57084011597&format=rss20';
    $ch = curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$head);
     $result = curl_exec($ch);

        return $result;
```

I've tried without setting a header but it also didn't worked.
Hope that somebody coud give me a clue.

Thank you!

Comment: What does `curl_error()` say?

Comment: Yes, what's the curl error or PHP error you get?

Comment: Why do you need headers for this page? It is already a RSS feed and I think setting those headers won't make much difference, right?

Comment: There is nothing in the error reponse :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is your problem: `$ur='http://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=57084011597&format=rss20';`. You're missing an "l".

```
$url='http://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=57084011597&format=rss20';
```

Also, there's a redirect so you'll need to add:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

This how I found out. I enabled verbose output using `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);` and saw this:

```
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< Location: http://www.facebook.com/common/browser.php
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< X-FB-Server: 10.43.97.37
< X-Cnection: close
< Date: Thu, 30 Jun 2011 06:48:54 GMT
< Content-Length: 0
```

**Update, tested and working:**

Facebook expects a user-agent string to be specified. Setting it with `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, '...');` seems to solve the problem. Here's an over-simplistic example which should solve your problem:

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init('http://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=57084011597&format=rss20');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, array('User-Agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1 Safari/534.45'));

$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: sorry for the $url. In the original document the setting were good, I've added curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); And it says that my browser is not compatible with that. What does that mean? I've also tried without the headers, but the response was the same

Comment: @Iosub - I did it on my Mac through the terminal (command line). I did get the same notice. I read through Google that RSS feeds require a "key" which yours doesn't seem to have. I'm assuming that you need to be "signed-in" or pass a valid key to be able to download the content.

Comment: I've tried that too. I've logged out from and access that url. I was still able to see that content in my browser window, but agin, nothig working with the curl

Comment: @Iosub - You need to set the user-agent. See my updated answer. I've tested the short example at the bottom and it works. No need for headers or anything else.

Comment: Good tutorial. Set the user-agent resolve my problem